# Hibernate session manager for bulk insertion and fetching at the same time

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, session

I am new to hibernate. I am facing problems with hibernate session problems. when i am trying to insert a data I will use
     session.openSession();

After completing the updation I am using session.flush();session.clear(); and session.close().
I don't how to maintain this. I am getting deadlock exception. At the same time of insertion i am opening another one session to fetch data.

Please help me.. This is my existing sample code

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("messageListenerReportSessionFactory")
private SessionFactory messageListenerReportSessionFactory;

    Session session = messageListenerReportSessionFactory.openSession();
    if(session != null && session.isOpen()){
        try{
            Transaction tx= session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("Update "+tableName+" set isUser = ? where id = ?");

            q.setInteger(0, 2);
            q.setLong(1, id);

            q.executeUpdate();
            tx.commit(); tx = null;

        }catch(Exception ex){
            PointelTraceLogger.logger.log(Level.ERROR, "[Audit] Error in updateUser() in com.pointel.application.database.pointelreport.MessageListenerReportDao");
            PointelTraceLogger.writeStackTrace(ex);
        }finally{
            session.clear();
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post some code, also working with the session like you do doesn't seem like you are using Spring but at least try to work around it.

Comment: i have posted the sample now..please check this

Comment: For starters you aren't rolling back the transaction when you have an error. However you are using Spring then why not let Spring handle all that for you?

Comment: can you give me a sample how to handle that in spring.. we are struggling with deadlock exception.

Comment: See the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-hibernate-straight).

Comment: HI Deinum. i have a doubt..if we are using sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() whether we need to open new session before that?

Comment: public Collection loadProductsByCategory(String category) {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from test.Product product where product.category=?")
                .setParameter(0, category)
                .list();
    }

Comment: No... Instead of only looking at the samples I suggest an actual read of the documentation, especially the section after what you read until now which explains declarative tx management.

Comment: Am using multiple threads. The i cant use getCurrentSession method right? please gimme some more idea

Comment: Yes you can. As stated read the documentation and just implement it.